# CSS half circles

Tags: css, css-shapes

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if it is possible to create half circles with CSS attached to each other and repeat them horizontally so it looks like a garland. They should be two different colors.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit for responsiveness**

http://jsfiddle.net/1v17e7uu/12/

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="big"></div>

div {
    width:10%;
    height:0px;
    padding-bottom:2.5%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    border-bottom-left-radius:100% 200%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:100% 200%;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
    div {
        width:20%;
        padding-bottom:5%;
    }
    div.big {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

For perfect circles just change the `height`'s to be half the `width`'s.

The trick to scale the size is the `padding-bottom` which is always applied based on the element's `width`. Of course now the sizes will be variable so you would have to add whatever breakpoints are appropriate. Then it's just a fixed number of elements with percentage `width`'s of `100/n` so they always reach across.

Comment: Awesome! This exactly what I mean! Problem is though that it is for a responsive theme and supposed to always reach across the whole screen. Do you know how I could achieve this?